# Jasper Reports fonts problem when stating in openjdk:15-alpine

Tags: java, docker, jasper-reports, alpine-linux

I know there are a lot of similar questions, but I didn't find exact my case

I have:

1. Spring boot application
2. pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
  <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
  <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
  <version>6.17.0</version>
</dependency>
```

3. src/main/resources/jasperreports_extension.properties

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.fonts=net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionsRegistryFactory
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.simple.font.families.myfamily=fonts/myfamily.xml
```

4. src/main/resources/fonts/myfamily.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fontFamilies>
    <fontFamily name="Tahoma">
        <normal><![CDATA[fonts/Tahoma/tahoma.ttf]]></normal>
        <pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Cp1251]]></pdfEncoding>
        <pdfEmbedded><![CDATA[true]]></pdfEmbedded>
        <exportFonts/>
        <locales>
            <locale><![CDATA[ru_RU]]></locale>
        </locales>
    </fontFamily>
</fontFamilies>
```

5. src/main/resources/fonts/Tahoma/tahoma.ttf

AND EVERYTHING WORKS FINE ! WHEN STARTING LOCALLY WITH ADOPT-OPENJDK-15 (sorry for uppercase)

Problems starting when starting on a server, where in docker my application starts in openjdk:15-alpine, there just some fonts included by default https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Fonts

and i'm getting an two errors
when hitting first time:

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /opt/openjdk-15/lib/libfontmanager.so: Error loading shared library libfreetype.so.6: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/openjdk-15/lib/libfontmanager.so)
```

and when hitting second time (and so on the following error everytime) It's interesting why always first tine comes one error but second and other times another error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class net.sf.jasperreports.engine.util.JRStyledTextParser] with root cause
```

I tried some solutions

1. Add JAVA_OPT to docker container

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
```

2. Added dependency to docker contaier

```
RUN apk update && apk upgrade \
   && apk add --no-cache ttf-dejavu
```

THAT WORKED FOR ME!!! (but not my case, because I don't want to add other dependecies, it could cause more problems with deploying my app on servers)

3. Switch to another jdk (not alpine) worked, but also not my case, because I have to use alpine version
4. Switch pdf encoding to

```
<pdfEncoding><![CDATA[Identity-H]]></pdfEncoding>
```

5. Tried to add
   default.jasperreports.properties

with

```
net.sf.jasperreports.default.font.name=Tahoma
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.font.name=Tahoma
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.encoding=Cp1252
net.sf.jasperreports.default.pdf.embedded=false
```

here I've got another NPE error, googled about it, and just found an answer to get away from that default properties, no one worked it out

So how to deal with those errors in ALPINE JDK ?

Comment: I think there's no way without installing some font packages such as ttf-dejavu or freetype (proposed solution 2). As you mentioned, Alpine vanilla image is very compact and contains the absolute minimal required packages, which doesn't include GUI support and proper fonts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there was no way without installing some font packages as Alex K has mentioned above.

I eventually figure it out when created empty Jasper template without any text, any forms, any fonts. And the same problem had been appeared.

And I had to move from Jasper to iText library, because for me was more important to keep jdk alpine version due to ci/cd and deployment settings

Comment: Hope you are aware of the itext license while using in project, it's AGPL one, some issue in using in commercial project